# Help with makedtx --- DocInput undefined

Tags: errors, package-writing, documentation, dtx

I am trying to generate a CTAN `.dtx`/`.ins` files for a package I have and I stumbled upon a problem that I can't solve nor find a way around. I am on a Ubuntu 18.04, with a LaTeX Live 2017.

Consider the couple of files (simplified, clearly):

`testp.sty`:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{testp}
\def\testp{Yay}
\endinput
```

and `testdoc.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{testp}
\begin{document}
    \testp
\end{document}
```

The second one compiles all right. Now I try to create the `dtx/ins` pair:

```
makedtx -author "Me" -src "testp\.sty=>testp.sty" -doc testdoc.tex testp
```

This generate the `testp.ins` and `testp.dtx` files. If I move them in another directory, and then run `latex` on the `testp.ins` file, the `testp.sty` file is correctly generated. But now, if I run `latex` on the `.dtx` file I have this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testp.dtx
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu))) (./testp.sty)
(./testp.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.40 \DocInput
              {testp.dtx}
?
```

If I add `\usepackage{doc}` to the `testdoc.tex` file (thanks 
[Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512982/help-with-makedtx-docinput-undefined?noredirect=1#comment1297276_512982)), I now have this error:

```
θ64° [romano:~/software/bugs/makedtx/check] % latex testp.dtx
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./testp.dtx
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/doc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)) (./testp.sty)
No file testp.aux.
(./testp.dtx

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.55 \NeedsTeXFormat
                    {LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
?
```

...so there is something I am doing wrong; can anyone shed some light?

Comment: `\DocInput` is defined by the `doc` package. You usually want to load it when documenting LaTeX packages. (ignore my previous, now deleted comment :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik --- thanks, that was an error for sure, but now I have another one... I feel I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is the missing `doc` package, which defines `\DocInput`.

The second problem is that the generated `.dtx` file looks like this:

```latex
%\iffalse
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*testp.sty>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\fi
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{testp}
\def\testp{Yay}
\endinput
%\iffalse
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</testp.sty>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\fi
```

and in the `\DocInput` run, when `%` are ignored, the two `\iffalse` above disappear and all what's left is everything from `\NeedsTeXFormat`. But remember, you're already after `\begin{document}`, and `\NeedsTeXFormat` is invalid here (as the error message says).

`makedtx` does not guard (I think it should) the code from being executed, so an error is raised. Section [**5 Examples**](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/support/makedtx/makedtx.pdf#section.5) of the `makedtx` documentation shows you that you need to put the code within `macrocode` blocks yourself:

> [image]

so your `testp.sty` should be changed to (comments added for illustration):

```latex
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{testp}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% Define a very important command:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\testp{Yay}
\endinput
%    \end{macrocode}
```

then in the typeset run, the code will be guarded by the `macrocode` environment and will be typeset correctly:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. I (wrongly) supposed from the `makedtx` description that it could take the `.sty` and manual file and generate `.dtx`/`.ins` with no changes, but I should have read all the manual...

Comment: @Rmano Read the epigraph in the Prologue (page iii) to the (fabulous) `arara` manual ;-) This way is, in my opinion, better, as it somewhat forces you to add documentation to each piece of code in your package, which is good (for the reader, that is, not for you ;-). However `makedtx` should probably parse each input line and wrap “unprotected” lines in `macrocode` blocks, as it's rather unusual to want code executed in this part of the process... A feature request, perhaps...

Comment: @Rmano Ooh, `xkcdcolors`! Finally colour names which make sense :D

Comment: Yep, so now you know the "full" example... ;-)